# How to write one javascript module, that can be adapted for slightly different use cases?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, module, prototype

I'm creating a JavaScript module which, when a (next or previous) button is clicked at the bottom of a modal, the current modal (4 in total) submits the data as an AJAX request, and then opens the next modal.

However, as you can see the code within each sub-module is almost identical (profile, details...). The only changes would be the '$modal' variable and the two ajax requests (one for GET and the other for POST).

I have attempted to use the Prototypal pattern (for my first time), and this did not work. Any ideas of a solution? Thanks

```
var application = (function() {

    // cache DOM
    var $modals = $('.modals');
    var $buttons = $modals.find('.form_buttons');

    function openModal() {
        var modalId = $(this).attr('data-modal');
        // Don't worry about this part, I still have to write the modal change
        console.log(modalId);
    }


    // Profile
    profile = (function() {
        // cache DOM
        var $modal = $modals.find('#modal_one');
        // bind events
        $modal.on('click', 'button.submit_button', submit);
        $modal.on('click', 'button.previous_button', submit);

        function submit() {
            $.ajax({})
                .done(function() {
                    openModal.call(this);
                });
        }
    })();

    // Details
    details = (function() {
        // cache DOM
        var $modal = $modals.find('#modal_two');
        // bind events
        $modal.on('click', 'button.submit_button', submit);
        $modal.on('click', 'button.previous_button', submit);

        function submit() {
            $.ajax({})
                .done(function() {
                    openModal.call(this);
                });
        }
    })();

    // Education
    education = (function() {
        // cache DOM
        var $modal = $modals.find('#modal_three');
        // bind events
        $modal.on('click', 'button.submit_button', submit);
        $modal.on('click', 'button.previous_button', submit);

        function submit() {
            $.ajax({})
                .done(function() {
                    openModal.call(this);
                });
        }
    })();

    // Employment
    employment = (function() {
        // cache DOM
        var $modal = $modals.find('#modal_four');
        // bind events
        $modal.on('click', 'button.submit_button', submit);
        $modal.on('click', 'button.previous_button', submit);

        function submit() {
            $.ajax({})
                .done(function() {
                    openModal.call(this);
                });
        }
    })();

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested

```
var application = (function () {

  // cache DOM
  var $modals = $('.modals');
  var $buttons = $modals.find('.form_buttons');

  function fn($modal, ajaxObj) {
    // bind events
    $modal.on('click', 'button.submit_button', submit);
    $modal.on('click', 'button.previous_button', submit);

    function openModal() {
      var modalId = $modal.attr('data-modal');
      // Don't worry about this part, I still have to write the modal change
      console.log(modalId);
    }

    function submit() {
      $.ajax(ajaxObj)
        .done(openModal);
    }
  }

  fn($modals.find('#modal_one'), { /* obj to pass to ajax call for modal_one */ });
  fn($modals.find('#modal_two'), { /* obj to pass to ajax call for modal_two */ });
  //... etc...

  //alternatively you could probably just loop '$modals' and call 'fn' for each of them. 
  //
  //Also, brought 'openModal' into 'fn' which makes it a bit more maintainable imo. This is not
  //required though. Instead you could just have it side outside of 'fn' and call using
  //openModal.call($modal) or better: just pass $modal as a regular parameter without using 'this'. 


})();
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thank you

Comment: you're welcome. Also both eventhandlers can be combined like so: `$modal.on('click', 'button.submit_button, button.previous_button', submit);`. Then refactoring even further (if you want) you can just inline the function `submit` since there's only one place left from which it is called. hth

Answer (score 0):

You can pass to your method the "suffix" of the tab name.

add to your form an attribute "rel" with the variable and bind that event outside your object

```
var application = (function() {

    // cache DOM
    var $modals = $('.modals');
    var $buttons = $modals.find('.form_buttons');

    function openModal() {
        var modalId = $(this).attr('data-modal');
        // Don't worry about this part, I still have to write the modal change
        console.log(modalId);
    }
     // Profile
    modalChange = function(tabName) {
        // cache DOM
        var $modal = $modals.find('#modal_' + tabName);
        // bind events
        $modal.on('click', 'button.submit_button', submit);
        $modal.on('click', 'button.previous_button', submit);
    };
})();

function submit() {
    $.ajax({})
            .done(function() {
        openModal.call(application.modalChange( $(this).attr("rel") );
    });
}
```